# Way to insert charcters between two characters using Vi Editing unix

Tags: regex, vi, editing

Imagine two characters `n` and `1`, where I need to insert a new character between them. We just need to input commands (end with <kbd>Esc</kbd>) like <kbd>i</kbd>—insert before cursor. This command leaves vi in input mode until you press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Now let's say there are range of two characters:

- `n` and `1`
- `n` and `2`
- `n` and `3`
- `n` and `4`
- `n` and `5`
- `n` and `6`
- `n` and `8`
- `n` and `9`
- ...so on.

e.g. "gin`Bulk`1" (added `Bulk` between `n` and `1`)

Now I need to insert a UNIQUE character between these. So instead of manually going to each line one-by-one, pressing <kbd>i</kbd>, then inserting, can I just do it with simple command in vi?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
:g/n and 1/s//n and x 1/g
```

If you do not understand this, then post a few lines of actual before and after data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I 100% understand, but try a regex replace:

```
:%s/n\([0-9]\)/nBulk\1/g
```

Which will replace all instances of n followed by a number with nBulk followed by the same number.  I notice you say UNIQUE in your question, so if by this you mean that the word to be inserted is different every time (so `n1` -> `nBulk1`, `n2` -> `nCat2` for example), then you need to explain your question more clearly, like is there some sort of pattern in the replacements?